# Difference between Camel AWS and AWS2 component?

Tags: apache-camel

What's the difference between aws and aws2 Camel component?

The documentation does not provide any information about that. Is AWS2 more or less powerful than AWS?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the end users, nothing will change, except the needed model classes coming from the SDK v2. So migrating should be a matter of changing imports and scheme. The first effort for the community was being able to obtain features parity between old and new components, and we did that.

reference and more detail : https://camel.apache.org/blog/2020/03/Camel3-AWS2-Whatsnew/